# In the context of KNN, why small K generates complex models?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

Section 1.4.8 of "Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective by Kevin Patrick Murphy" gives this figure (Figure 1.21(a)) to illustrate the error rate of a KNN classifier for different values of k:

[image: figure]

And gives the following explanation:

> We see that increasing K increases our error rate on the training set, because we are over-smoothing. As we said above, we can get minimal error on the training set by using K = 1, since this model is just memorizing the data.
>
> However, what we care about is generalization error, which is the expected value of the misclassification rate when averaged over future data (see Section 6.3 for details). This can be approximated by computing the misclassification rate on a large independent test set, not used during model training. We plot the test error vs K in Figure 1.21(a) in solid red (upper curve). Now we see a U-shaped curve: for complex models (small K), the method overfits, and for simple models (big K), the method underfits.

Why small K generates more complex models?

Answer (score 2):

kNN in essence is a density based classifier. You pick a point, expand a "window" around that point and pick the most frequent class within the window. It differs from "parzen window" (kernel density estimation) type classifiers in one aspect: the window size is variable - it expands up until it encapsulates $k$ observations.

With this picture think about how different $k$ parameters will influence the density estimation on your feature space. With small $k$ numbers you will get narrower "windows" - the density will have a lower bandwidth. And with higher $k$ values the density estimation will happen over larger areas. Since smaller $k$ models are more sensitive to abrupt changes - the models are more complex.

It might also be useful to think about the other extreme - $k = \infty$. Here the density will be estimated over the whole feature space and you will get the most simple classifier possible: for every new sample predict the most frequent class from the training data.

---

This can best be illustrated with an example of regression on one dimensional feature space. Say you have a a model that predicts a continuous value $y$, given a continuous feature $x$. And you have 10 points as your training set. The data can be visualised this way:

[image: screen1]

Then fitted models with $k = \{1,2,3,4\}$ would look like this:

[image: screen2]

In the above picture note one thing: the number of distinct values (steps) returned by the model is decreasing by 1 with every increase of the parameter $k$.

And of course the model for $k = \infty$ would produce:

[image: screen3]

Comment: about "the other extreme - $=∞$", I guess I saw somewhere the possible maximum of K is N, the number of training examples.

Comment: That is true, I just used $\infty$ to indicate "as many as possible". For example the title above the last picture (for $k = \infty$) has $k = 10$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you please provide the code plotting out these figures?

Comment: @yaojp already deleted, sorry. But I used `knn.reg` function from `FNN` library to quickly get the predictions. And plots were custom made.

Comment: Thanks all the time. Would you please give some hint or keywords for the red lines? I've searched something like "steps knn regression" and find nothing like that plot. I guess If I learn more about the plot (red line), I might learn more about the problem.

Comment: I see. This is kNN algorithm just for regression. For an unseen sample - you get the nearest neighbour. But instead of assigning the class, you take the numeric value of that neighbour as your prediction. If you use k=3 - you find 3 nearest neighbours, and average their numeric values to get your prediction. The black lines in the plots are your training set. Their "x" (feature) is on the x axis and their height represents their numeric value. The red lines depict what a model would return based on a certain value of "x". Does this help?

Comment: For example, looking at the k=1 plot. For a new sample with x=6 you would assign a value of ~35. And for x=8 a value of ~60. Thus the number of steps represent the number of distinct values your model might predict, given the training data.

Answer (score 1):

Because, when you choose small $K$, the classifier's decisions will tend to be affected by local changes more easily. The easiest way to visualize it is for $K=1$, which means the decision boundary is affected by every point in the dataset, which means additional complexity drawing them. This is like trying to find a set of rules to please everybody. For example, if you have a lot of points of class $1$ clustered together in some area, just one point of class $2$ will create its local neighborhood around the region and the decision boundary will be affected. There is a wonderful picture depicting this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/367010/training-error-in-knn-classifier-when-k-1).